# How to create plot with x-axis as factor of numeric intervals by number and multi difference variable in box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a boxplot x-axis is `Umur` the y-axis is `Ton`. The problem the x-axis - age - is not arranged from the smallest to the biggest.

Please help to correct my function:

```
  ton.ame.1%>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Umur, y = sum_by_group,color=Tahun)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape = 18, aes(group=Tahun), 
           position=position_dodge(0.85), 
           color="black", size=2)+
  ggtitle("Produktivitas TBS [Ton/Ha] di ABCDEFGH's Estate Periode 2015 - 2019") +                     
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "black", size = 12,face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "black", size = 12,face = "bold", hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  xlab('Umur Tanam') +
  ylab('TBS [ Ton/Ha ]')
```

[boxplot multivariabel and random with x-axis as numeric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yEDq.png)

Comment: I suspect this x axis variable is a character or an ordered factor. please Check that with `class(Umur)`. It actually is correctly ordered, but characters are ordered differently than numbers: "10" < "9" evaluates to TRUE, because the comparison is character-wise: 1<9.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank, @GuedesBF 
Its Work and Done.
I have been check class(Umur) in  manual dataset in excel before corected class "Number Stored as Text" and corrected to be " Convert to Number".